# Multiple directives in apache2 / httpd via command line?

Tags: apache-http-server, httpd

I know you can specify one directive at the command line using this syntax:

```
httpd -c "DocumentRoot ."
```

But what if I also want to specify other options? Is this possible?

I know there are static switches like -p, -d etc. but I really want to launch a http daemon without any conf file so want the ability to specify all configuration in the command itself.

Don't question me on why I prefer this, that's beyond the scope of the question. I just want to launch a bunch of daemons by copying and pasting a single command. I tried with a here document but I'm hoping there's a more direct approach. I also do not want to use a different binary like lighttpd. I want the industry standard capability of the latest version of Apache.

**EDIT** - I tried this and it's still trying to use port 80:

```
httpd     -c "DocumentRoot ."     -c 'Listen 7000'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that older versions of Apache don't support multiple '-c' options - such as httpd on Mac OS Lion. But it's fine on Ubuntu 12.04:

```
apache2 \
    -f /dev/null \
    -C "DocumentRoot $PWD" \
    -C 'Listen 7000' \
    -C 'PidFile /tmp/pidfile' \
    -C 'ErrorLog /dev/stdout' \
    -D FOREGROUND
```

Credits: https://gist.github.com/thwarted/7672130

Comment: Thank you for a working example. Note how `-f /dev/null` is used here to suppress the original configuration. (I think that missing the `-f` option was the root cause of the original issue. That it was not really a question of whether multiple `-c` or `-C` were allowed at that time.)